# MYSQL: select 1 record per product, prefer if client is set?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to remove duplicate `productID`'s, making the query pick the record that has a `clientID` over the one that doesn't.

The idea is to link files (like manuals) to a product. However, when a file is also linked to a client, it should take priority over the globally linked file as that file will be for this specific client only.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, the tables look like this:

**client_products**

```
| client | product |
```

**products**

```
| ID | name |
```

**product_specifications**

```
| filepath | product | client |
```

Now, this is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT products.*, ps.specification, cp.client
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_specifications ps on ps.product = products.ID
RIGHT JOIN client_products cp ON cp.product = products.ID
WHERE cp.client = 1
AND products.ID = cp.product
ORDER BY products.name
```

Obviously, I'm doing a basic select query with some joins. I'm grouping it by the `products.ID` to make sure I don't get the product back twice, but this does not guarantee that I will get the specific client's linked specification file, right? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Example results:
What i'm getting (without the `GROUP BY`)

```
| ID | specification | client |
|  1 |       1       |    1   |
|  1 |       1       |  NULL  |
|  2 |       3       |  NULL  |
```

What I would like to get when the client column is not null:

```
| ID | specification | client |
|  1 |       1       |    1   |
|  2 |       3       |  NULL  |
```

### [See my sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9d705/1/0)

Comment: What's the primary key on the product_specifications table?

Comment: @Strawberry there is none. The only primary key here is in products. The rest are just joining tables. My idea was: select products  > where relationship between product and client exists (product_clients) > select specifications > overrule global specifications if it has been linked to a client specificially

Comment: If a table doesn't have a PRIMARY KEY, then it isn't really a table. There must be at least one way of uniquely identifying rows in a table. For instance, the PK on the client_products table is (client,product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved a similar fallback problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39439185/5563083). The "trick" is to use a LEFT JOIN to look if a client specific file exists:

```
select p.*, ps.*
from client_products cp
join products p on p.ID = cp.product
left join product_specifications ps
  on  ps.product = p.ID
  and (ps.client = 1 or ps.client IS NULL)
left join product_specifications ps1 
  on  ps1.product = p.ID
  and ps1.client = 1
  and ps.client IS NULL
where cp.client = 1
  and ps1.client IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9d705/29

If you only need one column from the `product_specifications` table, you could also try this one:

```
select p.*, coalesce(ps.specification, ps1.specification) as specification
from client_products cp
join products p on p.ID = cp.product
left join product_specifications ps
  on  ps.product = p.ID
  and ps.client = 1
left join product_specifications ps1
  on  ps1.product = p.ID
  and ps1.client IS NULL
where cp.client = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9d705/34

You join the `product_specifications` table twice. Once for `client = 1` and once for `client IS NULL`. Using `COALESCE()` you select the second one only if the first one doesn't exit.

Comment: Yeahhh this is perfect, thank you! I didn't even know a function like `coalesce` existed! Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the kernel of your problem can be solved with the following (I may have amended column names slightly)...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM product_specifications x 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT product_id
            , MAX(client_id) client_id 
         FROM product_specifications 
        GROUP 
           BY product_id
     ) y
    ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
   AND (y.client_id = x.client_id OR y.client_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! This seems to be getting results, but not the ones I want. It's now returning only products that have specifications AND are linked to any client. It should return all products, with or without specifications.

Comment: This is the product_specifications table, so obviously it's only concerned with products with specifications. To get all products, you just LEFT JOIN the above to the other table.