# How to grab just 1 record in a single pass?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I've got a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
recordID | peopleID | AddressTypeID | Address | ActiveInd
10       | 102      | 1             | 4th Ave | 1
11       | 102      | 3             | 4th Ave | 1
12       | 203      | 3             | 5th Ave | 1
```

I'm trying to get a record at the `peopleID` level wherever `AddressTypeID = 1` but if that doesn't exist, then get a record for `AddressTypeID = 3`.

So result set would be this:

```
recordID | peopleID | AddressTypeID | Address | ActiveInd
10       | 102      | 1             | 4th Ave | 1
12       | 203      | 3             | 5th Ave | 1
```

I don't think `coalesce` is the answer, and thought of trying a large `case` statement, but I would get duplicate records using `case`, right?

Comment: And if there is nothing with `AddressTypeID = 3`?

Comment: You could do a subselect for the addresss, sort by AddressTypeId, filter by  AddressTypeId IN(1,3) and LIMIT 1.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel then nothing.

Comment: @Evert yeah I could do a subselect, but I'd like to keep this with just one pass if possible

Comment: What does that mean: "at the peopleID level"?

Comment: basically no duplicates per PeopleID

Comment: So you want one row per `peopleID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39439185/5563083) (which is dealing with failover languages):

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1
    on  t1.peopleID = t.peopleID
    and t1.AddressTypeID = 1
    and t.AddressTypeID  = 3
where t.AddressTypeID in (1, 3)
  and t1.recordID is null
```

I changed the sample data to cover more cases:

```
| recordID | peopleID | AddressTypeID | Address | ActiveInd |
|----------|----------|---------------|---------|-----------|
|       10 |      102 |             1 | 4th Ave |         1 |
|       11 |      102 |             3 | 4th Ave |         1 |
|       12 |      203 |             3 | 5th Ave |         1 |
|       13 |      304 |             1 | 6th Ave |         1 |
|       14 |      405 |             2 | 7th Ave |         1 |
```

And the result is:

```
| recordID | peopleID | AddressTypeID | Address | ActiveInd |
|----------|----------|---------------|---------|-----------|
|       10 |      102 |             1 | 4th Ave |         1 |
|       12 |      203 |             3 | 5th Ave |         1 |
|       13 |      304 |             1 | 6th Ave |         1 |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d48b92/2